# Can a sum of different exponentials be rewritten as a sum of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

In a textbook I recently read that

$$ A_1e^{x}+A_2e^{-x}+A_3e^{ix}+A_4e^{-ix}$$

(where $A_n\in\mathbb{C}$, $A_i\neq A_j\;\forall\;i\neq j$) can be rewritten as

$$ A'_1\sin x+A'_2\cos x+A'_3\sinh x+A'_4\cosh x$$
(where $A'_n\in\mathbb{R}$).

Is that true? How can I prove that?

Comment: What do you mean? A sum of complex numbers can be real.

Comment: It can. A real number is a complex number with its imaginary part that equals zero. Consider:

$$ (1+i) +(1-i)=2 $$

LHS is complex, RHS is real.

Comment: If you don't want to explain just don't comment. Please, be respectful.

Comment: The second part of my question has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170286/generalization-of-eulers-formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that 
$$
\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \\
\cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \\
\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} \\
\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}
$$
From that you can deduce
$$
A_1e^x = A_1\cosh(x) + A_1\sinh(x) \\
A_2e^{-x} = A_2\cosh(x) - A_2\sinh(x) \\
A_3e^{ix} = A_3\cos(x) + A_3i\sin(x) \\
A_4e^{-ix} = A_4\cos(x) - A_4i\sin(x)
$$
Summing everything gives us :
$$
A_1e^x + A_2e^{-x} + A_3e^{ix} + A_4e^{-ix} =  \\
(A_1+A_2)\cosh(x) + (A_3 + A_4)\cos(x) + (A_1 - A_2)\sinh(x) + i(A_3- A_4)\sin(x)
$$
Therefore you get that 
$$
\begin{cases}
A_1' = i(A_3 - A_4) \\
A_2' = A_3 + A_4 \\
A_3' = A_1 - A_2 \\
A_4' = A_1 + A_2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If one wants to get $A'_1 A'_2 \cdots$, from $A_1, A_2\cdots$ no need to solve the system, just use the other substitution (your first one)

Comment: Yes! Perfect, that's the right answer. I was trying the same path, but I did I mistake in the calculations :) Can I make another very correlated question? Can I rewrite $ ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}$ as $ c \cos(x+d)$ ($a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$)?