# Generalization of Euler's Formula

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Euler's formula states that, for any real number x:

$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Can it be generalized in that way?

$$ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}=c\cos(x+d)$$

where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ and $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$.
Of course if $a=b=1$  and $c=2$, $d=0$ this is the common Euler's fomula, but it is true that for every $a,b$ I can rewrite a sum of complex exponentials as a **single** cosine? If it is, what is the relationship between these constants?

Comment: What happens when $b=0$?

Comment: Why does it matters?

Comment: @AlessandroZunino you get sine terms in that case

Comment: So? Please forgive me, I do not follow you.

Comment: The result has to be a linear combination of sine ***and*** cosine is what he's saying.

Comment: I really don't see why it matters. if $a=b=1$,$c=2$ and $d=0$ you only have a cosine. I'm asking if there is a way to rewrite a sum of complex exponentials as a **single** cosine, I'm not interested in other cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a sum of different exponentials be rewritten as a sum of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170160/can-a-sum-of-different-exponentials-be-rewritten-as-a-sum-of-trigonometric-and-h)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Can you please remove the flag?

Comment: @AlessandroZunino My point is that if $b=0$, then the left-hand side is a complex function, while the right-hand side is real, so clearly it is not true for every pair $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, as it's written in Stefano's answer $a$ and $b$ must be complex conjugates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your formula is true for any $x \in \mathbb R$. You can write it as

$$ ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}- \frac{c}{2}(e^{id} e^{ix}+ e^{-id}e^{-ix}) = 0,$$

that is

$$ \left(a - \frac{c}{2}e^{id}\right) e^{ix}+ \left( b - \frac{c}{2}e^{-id}\right) e^{-ix} =0.$$

Now we can use the fact that $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ are linearly independent to get

$$a = \frac{c}{2}e^{id}, \quad b = \frac{c}{2}e^{-id}.$$

This implies

$$ c = 2 (ab)^{1/2}, \quad  \cos d = \frac{a+b}{2 (ab)^{1/2}}.$$

Since we require $c$ and $d$ to be real, then $ab$ has to be a positive real number and $a+b$ has to be real. This is possible only if $a$ and $b$ are complex conjugates: $b = \bar a$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm more interested in the inverse relationships, i.e. how to write $d:=d(a,b)$ and $c:=c(a,b)$. Can you please edit the answer?

Comment: Edited. Hope this helps somehow!

Comment: Great! It surely will help, thank you again!

Comment: Just a last issue: where did you used that $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$? From the written relationships is not obvious that these constants are real. Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: No it's not. This constrains your $a$ and $b$: they can't just be any two complex numbers, but $ab$ must be a (non negative) real number, and $a+b$ has to be real, too.

Comment: Ok, perfect. This is indeed very important to me. If you also add this comment to your answer that could help other people. Thank you again!

Comment: There you go! You are welcome ;)

Comment: Minor detail: $a=b=0$ is also possible, of course.